# Magento: import products from csv file programmatically using a custom separator

Tags: magento

I have created a custom module to import products from csv file, but I don't know how to specify a custom separator for example "~" in the place of the default separator of columns ";".

Thnaks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have written your custom Module, you can specify Any separator by using the separator in the appropriate PHP Methods like fgetcsv. It is the Parameter $delimiter in that method. You then parse your custom Format and create the csv Format which Magento needs. I have done it like that for the Import. Share Code if you need more in depth help.

Comment: Thank you a lot mpaepper, I have added my custom delimiter to fgetcsv and it works now ;)